# Custom Search in Sidebar and show result at the right wide pane

Tags: visualforce

I added a custom search at the left sidebar of Salesforce by using Visualfore Area Component. It appears like:

[image]

My "Go" button at here is a  and it calls a controller method. So the problem is, when I click the "Go" button, how can I open a page at right wide pane, just like the standard Salesforce search "Go"?

I have used the following code

```
    <apex:commandButton id="gsearch" value="Go" action="{!search}" onclick="parent.location.href ='/apex/SearchResults'"/>
```

to call the next vf page SearchResults. But it is opening the vf page blank though the controller method is doing proper search(I can see from debug log).

Answer (score 3):

To re-affirm your requirement is that

1) You've a search component in the sidebar

2) On hitting 'Go' in this search component in the sidebar, you want the search results to show in the right pane.

You can use the approach suggested [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AztfIAC) to create a custom link and pass the search parameters to a Visualforce page.

e.g. Your VF page would look something like

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Five9ScreenPop" action="{!NumCases}"> 
    <apex:form>
         <div style="text-align: center;"> 
             <apex:inputText value="{!searchString}" label="Account/Contact Search"/>
             <apex:commandButton value="Search Contacts & Accounts" action="{!search}"/> 
         </div>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Replace the custom button with a a custom link

In your controller, get the search string params and do the appropriate processing based on the specified parameters.

So, you need not use

```
onclick="parent.location.href ='/apex/SearchResults'
```

This should work. If you face issues, I'd recommend isolating by testing the VF page independently by passing the same params first and then hooking it up to the sidebar custom button.

Comment: Could you please explain, where I have to create custom link? 
My homepage component is a vf page. From this vf page I want to take input and open the 2nd vf page at the right wide pane with results.
I can see that my homepage component is taking the input and doing search. But the 2nd home page is opening blank. Which means there is some break in the connection between two pages.

Comment: Your custom link would be in the sidebar VF page/ component.

Comment: can you please add a piece of code so that I can understand.